# What is differences between primary actions and secondary actions for checkbox?

Tags: design-patterns, checkboxes, material

[image: material design]

While reading about [lists in material design](https://www.material.io/design/components/lists.html#types), I could not understand what Primary and Secondary actions refer to for checkboxes. I could not find any information about it. What is the difference between them, especially for check boxes? Please suggest a few examples.

Image 1 is about secondary actions and 2 is about primary actions.

Comment: Could you give us the link to the page where these images are from and where it is said that these are primary/secondary actions.

Comment: WIthout a source, I can ONLY SPECULATE: Place the checkbox *in front of* the item if selection of items (=checking the checkbox) is the main (=primary) action. Place the checkbox *after* the item if the list of items is mainly for something else, and the checkbox supports a secondary function.

Comment: Link https://www.material.io/design/components/lists.html#types）

Answer (score 1):

The text of that section is short but pretty straight-forward:

> 1. Secondary action
>      This checkbox is the list item’s secondary action.
> 2. Primary action
>      This checkbox is both the list item’s primary action **and state indicator**.

In the case of a secondary section, the checkbox is a simple selection while the list item can present other information as well (e.g. the images in your example). In a primary case, the main purpose of the list item is to be selected.

Basically it's about wether to place the selection element in a dominant or a less obtrusive position.